# geoserver support to proxy other tiling services?

Tags: geoserver

I'd like to use a central server to provide a common location for all of our mapping / imagery resources.  Our data is primarily in the form of geotiffs with a variety of base layers from various sources on the web.

Geoserver, given a set of geotiffs, does a nice job of serving up tiles (via WMTS or TMS).  However, I don't know of a way to easily proxy other external sources of data like the sample base layers from http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like many services implement a WMS layer (or don't make it public).  Currently we have logic in our application to special case various web services but it is a bit of hack.  Ideally I'd like to present a common web services interface to all our tiling providers.  This would enable WMS clients like world wind applications to "just work".

My only thought right now is to build a small python web service that would expose a list of capabilities via WMS and then add this service into geoserver as a cascading WMS store.  This seems like a lot of work to simply serve up map tile URLs.

I am curious if this this problem has been solved before or if there is an easier solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You might want to check out [MapProxy](http://mapproxy.org/). It is an open source proxy for geospatial data. It caches, accelerates and transforms data from existing map services and serves any desktop or web GIS client.

[image]

It reads data from:

- WMS sources (1.0.0–1.3.0)
- TMS/WMTS sources Mapserver and Mapnik
  configurations
- any TileCache, Google Maps or Bing compatible source

It can also

- cache data on filesystem, as MBTiles or inside CouchDB
- reproject WMS sources to other SRS
- store identical images just once (e.g. ocean tiles)
- embed watermark in tiles
- merge multiple sources
- limit sources to polygon areas

MapProxy is also a full compliant WMS server and supports any WMS client (desktop and web). It supports WMS responses from cached data:

- merges tiles and scales or reprojects images
- accelerates existing WMS 10 to 100 times

and cascaded WMS services:

- multi-threaded requests
- merges multiple sources
- adds transparency to opaque layers
- reprojects on-the-fly

It also supports combinations of cached and cascaded layers:

- respond to GetLegendGraphic requests
- cascade GetFeatureInfo requests with optional XSL transformations
- limit sources to polygon areas
- convert WMS versions and image formats
- support for non-image raster data like DEMs

You can also pre-generate the tile cache for better performance.

It also comes with a flexible authorization API that allows you to add fine-grained control over services and layers.

Comment: This is the best answer to the question, but should be taken with the recommendation that you should never do this on external services that you do not control - at the very least it's a performance nightmare, and more typically it's against terms of service and will result in your service being suspended.

Answer (score 0):

Your creating a bottleneck by proxying external services through your server. Also going to slow down the performance of your web map by forcing one server to process all requests.

The only reason I could maybe see a reason for this is for security. But even then your better off securing the endpoint instead and passing a token along.