# How do I configure GeoWebCache to read a TMS (GoogleMaps or OSM)

Tags: google-maps, geowebcache, tile-map-service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [geoserver support to proxy other tiling services?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31696/geoserver-support-to-proxy-other-tiling-services)

Probably a newbe question, with a simple answer, but I can't find enough detail in the GWC documentation.

I would like to set up GWC so that it reads a TMS (At the moment, just GoogleMap or OSM) and then makes this available as a WMS layer through GWC.

Is this possible, and if so, where do I configure it? I have been looking through the documentation on how to edit and add layers in geowebcache.xml, but I can't see the extact syntax for adding a TMS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: http://geowebcache.org/docs/1.2.1/services/tms.html - NOTE: TMS does not provide a way to communicate the SRS