# Can I create a TMS layer on geoserver or geowebcache

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, tile-map-service

I have GeoServer stood up and use it to server out a variety of different data sources and layers.  I would also like to be able to cache tiles (TMS).  Problem that I am running into is that I would like to cache TMS tiles in geoserver/geowebcache, however instead of a local data source I would like to use an external data source to create the cache.  It looks like you can feed a WMS Layer into geowebcache to create a new cache layer and then you can seed that layer.  Almost exactly what I want except for I want to feed in a TMS source not a WMS source.

IE docs say you can create like so:

Add Layer

Sample request:

```
Given a layer.xml file as the following:

<wmsLayer>
  <name>layer1</name>
  <mimeFormats>
    <string>image/png</string>
  </mimeFormats>
  <gridSubsets>
    <gridSubset>
      <gridSetName>EPSG:900913</gridSetName>
    </gridSubset>
  </gridSubsets>
  <wmsUrl>
    <string>http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms</string>
  </wmsUrl>
  <wmsLayers>topp:states</wmsLayers>
</wmsLayer>
curl -v -u geowebcache:secured -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d @layer.xml  "http://localhost:8080/geowebcache/rest/layers/layer1.xml"
```

Would it be possible to feed in  that points to a server serving out tiles?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after something like MapProxy.
Perhaps this question will help you.

[geoserver support to proxy other tiling services?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31696/geoserver-support-to-proxy-other-tiling-services)