# External Web Map Server (Tile WMS) for geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wms

Can I add to geoserver Tiled WMS layer?

For example Tile WMS:

https://example-server.maps.eu/layer1/11-1115-700

Comment: Have a look at this answer for another option http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/31696/

Comment: MapProxy is good solutions, I will try it

Comment: I just want to add that MapProxy is not the only application enabling this functionality.

Comment: The link doesn't work for me, is it correct?

Comment: Correct link is [https://m3-mapserver.mapy.cz/base-m/12-2237-1401](https://m3-mapserver.mapy.cz/base-m/12-2237-1401)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no ability to cascade a XYZ layer